# php: How to ignore letter case within a preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to match text from a string, whilst ignoring it's letter case. My example fails if the letter cases are not identical.

```
/*
  $text:  fOoBaR
  $str:   little brown Foobar
  return: little brown <strong>Foobar</strong>
*/
function bold($text, $str) {
    // This fails to match if the letter cases are not the same
    // Note: I do not want to change the returned $str letter case.
    return preg_replace('/('.str_replace(array("/", "\\"), array("\/", "\\"), $text).')/', "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
}

$phrase = [
    'little brown Foobar' => 'fOoBaR',
    'slash / slash' => 'h / sl',
    'spoon' => 'oO',
    'capital' => 'CAPITAL',
];

foreach($phrase as $str => $text)
    echo bold($text, $str) . '<br>';
```

Comment: Add modifier `i` to the regexp. `')/'` will be `')/i'`. Also, instead of `$text` in regexp is more safe to use result of `preg_quote` function. So .. `preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($text) . '/i', '<strong>$0</strong>', $str);`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks dude. You helped me out yesterday as well. :D How comes you don't write your replies as answers tho?

Comment: I do not like to write too much text or a lot of explanations. Especially when the answer is one-liner.

Comment: @Cheery add the answer, I'll remove mine. You beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: @slapyo I do not care about the point, keep yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, a couple of modifications for the line

```
return preg_replace('/('.str_replace(array("/", "\\"), array("\/", "\\"), $text).
                     ')/', "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
```

First, use modifier `/i` for the case-insensitive regexp.

Second, escape `$text` for the use in regexp as it might have symbols specific for the regexp (it also allows you to remove all those replacements that you have).

Third, no need in capturing the group, use the whole part of the string that fits the regexp by `$0`

```
return preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($text, '/').'/i','<strong>$0</strong>',$str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the case insensitive modifier, `i`, to the regular expression.

```
function bold($text, $str) {
    // This fails to match if the letter cases are not the same
    // Note: I do not want to change the returned $str letter case.
    return preg_replace('/('.str_replace(array("/", "\\"), array("\/", "\\"), $text).')/i', "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, waited some time, thought that you will not undelete it and wrote all 3 modifications. Keep it anyway.